# How to make the local host accessible to others within the company

Tags: javascript, iis

Have website created and hosted in Windows 7 IIS 7.5, have also assigned the IP address. I want this IP address to be accessed within the company, how to achive this. If any user within the company accesses this IP address, he should be able to view the website which has client javascript. How to achieve this, it is for Intranet only.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is open up the firewall.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb545423.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set this in the windows firewall. Choose *advanced settings*, *inbound rules* and double click *World Wide Web Services*, mark *Enabled/Allow the connection* and change the scope to your intranet using the 'scope' tab (you can create a range of ip-addresses that are allowed there).